# jQuery Accordion needs to ALWAYS show table in each div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, jquery-ui-accordion

I am using an accordion style menu to toggle the next div area when you click its parent h3 element.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div.accordian-content> div').hide();
    $('div.accordian-content> h3').click(function() {
    $(this).next('div').slideToggle('medium')
    .siblings('div:visible').slideUp('medium');
});
});
```

the code works fine with the following structure.

```
<div class='accordian-content'>
<h3>Some title</h3>
<div>content to be toggled</div>
</div>
```

The problem is that I'm trying to use a table in between the h3 and the next div and I want the table to always be shown, but when you put a table in there the parent h3 toggling breaks.

```
<div class='accordian-content'>
<h3>Covers </h3>
<table id='covers'>Table content </table>
    <div>Ajax content</div>
</div>
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated, as I have spent way to much time on this silly thing.

Comment: You forgot to add another closing `});` at the end of your jQuery code. I assume that's a copy-paste error.

Comment: you are correct it was a copy paste error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `next('div')` with `nextAll('div')` and you should be fine.  http://jsfiddle.net/VJCV9/

Comment: that almost works, but is shows all the following div's before it hides them and looks very strange to the end user.

Comment: That's what your code tells it to do. Replace `slideToggle()` and `slideUp()` with `hide()` where appropriate, or set `display:none` on those divs in your stylesheet.

Comment: I am not having much luck with that.  I think the issue is that both of the fore-mentioned blocks of code exist inside the accordian-content div.  Let me clarify.  the sections that have tables, use an image button in the cells to populate the following div with some content.  The div sections that dont have a table, have static HTML content.  When I try to combine both methods it breaks functionality for the areas that include tables.

Comment: That sounds much more complicated than the code you provided in your question. You may want to submit a new question, and provide a jsFiddle of your own with a more complete sample of your code.

Answer (score 0):

As far as know, tables dont `slideUp()` and also, should `</div be </div>`?  `$(this).next('div')` needs to be `.next(table).children(div)`

Comment: the </div was a typo i have fixed it in my post code.  your code partially fixed the issue.  now when you click the h3 element the table and the following div are toggling.  I would like the table to always be shown.